# Extend context menu in the subject of outlook 2010/2013

Tags: c#, outlook, contextmenu, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I have a small Outlook 2010/2013 Add-In written in C#. It adds additional context menu entries if the selected text in the Email body fits some pattern. For this I used a ribbon.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui" onLoad="Ribbon_Load">
    <ribbon/>
    <contextMenus>
        <contextMenu idMso="ContextMenuReadOnlyMailText">
            <button id="DoSomethingButton" insertAfterMso="Copy" getLabel="GetLabel"
                getImage="GetImage" onAction="DoSomething" getVisible="IsTextSelected"
                getScreentip="GetTip" />
        </contextMenu>
    </contextMenus>
</customUI>
```

That works fine.
Now I want to extend that it also add some context menu entries if the user selects some text in the subject of an Email.

[image: Extend the context menu]

Unfortunately I was not able to find any Microsoft Documentation how to do that. I am sure this is possible, because auto-correct also works in the subject field, but I just cannot find how. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

That menu is not extensible. Spellchecker is an integral part of that control, it is not added dynamically by an addin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It put a full stop to my search for this possibility. I wanted to add custom context menu to Outlook message subject line. Now, i will stop.

Answer (score 0):

The Ribbon UI extensibility model doesn't provide any idMso values for these context menus. You can all possible customizations described in the [Extending the User Interface in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee692172(v=office.14).aspx) article in MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by outlook 2010/2013 addin? Single addin supporting both the versions of outlook?

As there are few functionalities which are deprecated from 2010.

Comment: Yes one add-in but with support for both outlook versions. I am sure there are different functionalities, but here I am asking for "how to extend the subject context menu". Unfortunately it is not possible as it was already answered.

Comment: did you use ribbons in ur addin?

Comment: No, I do not need a ribbon for my functionality.